# Web Interfaces: What is a good way to display many static fields?

Tags: layout, user-interface, readability, heuristics

My web applications have pages that display many static fields.

I know that poor layout invariably leads to information overload and poor readability.

My Question:

> Are there any best-practices or heuristics for laying out a screen that contains many static fields?

Ordinarily, I would reference Bill Scott and Theresa Neil's [excellent book](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/explore), but I can't seem to find any guidance for this issue.

Here are some guidelines that I'm inclined to follow:

1. Group related fields.
2. Position the major (or parent) fields towards the top and the left. Position the minor (or child) fields towards the bottom and right.
3. Don't feel obliged to fill every pixel. Consider white space if it will improve readability.
4. Favor [progressive disclosure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure) wherever possible.
5. Consider an [accordion control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a [Details on Demand](http://www.welie.com/patterns/showPattern.php?patternID=details-on-demand) approach would work well. Ask yourself which data are absolutely and immediately relevant to the user and group those, while hiding the other data. You can always provide an 'Expand' link or control that would allow a user to view the details if desired.

(It's good to see that you're looking at interface design patterns. They are often overlooked!)

Answer (score 1):

I work on HR software and have faced this problem many times. One thing that we keep seeing in feedback when we introduce collapse controls or any progressive disclosure pattern really is that our users don't like the way those types of "web 2.0" (their words lol) pages don't print out. So just a reminder if your user base still insists on printing large pages of data include a print media stylesheet.

Depending on how large your set of data is I'd seriously consider a some search functionality or a sorting mechanism. Many times when the data set is large different users have different priorities and allowing customization is the only way to satisfy a wide audience.

Comment: They print forms? Wow. There is more in users' behaviour, Horatio, than is dreamt of in a programmer's philosophy ...

Comment: Tom - Great feedback. I'm still inclined to believe that there's some way to balance the competing concerns; but your words of wisdom are borne of experience, which makes them very credible.

Comment: @twic Yeah I am constantly amazed how much our users print stuff out. We occasionally get complaints about not being able to effectively print edit screens! These are screens filled with form elements that may or may not be committed to the db yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you pretty much answered your own question, especially the grouping of important fields tied to progressive disclosure.